# Incremental Formula for Copied Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to copy a column but the copied will have incremental numbers. For example, Column A has "8 Participants and 3 Facilitators". I would like to make it copy it in another column by giving each entry a unique value as "Participant 1, Participant 2, Participant 3...Participant 8, Facilitator 1, Facilitator 2, Facilitator 3. How can I do this without doing manually? Please see the attached photo.

[image]

Comment: It's done I got this formulat after I posted my questions

=A1 & IF(A1="","",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))

Comment: You can post it as an answer